# Laying out input elements using display:table-cell

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to write a CSS class that allows me to sit form elements (mixed button and text inputs) in a line so that they abut. I'm using `display:table` on a parent, and wrapping each element in a container with `display:table-cell`, and it works fine except for one bug that I can't figure out a way around.

So for example, parent is `control-group`, the element wrappers are `control-group-item`, and the elements themselves are `control-group-input`.

```
.control-group
  .control-group-item
    .control-group-input{type: "text"}
  .control-group-item
    .control-group-input{type: "submit"}
```

CSS of this (I've normalized font size/line height/padding/browser weirdness and all form elements are inline-blocked etc.):

```
.control-group {
    display: table;

.control-group-item {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

gives this, which is OK:

[image: Autosized inputs]

However, I ideally need it to fill a grid column of undetermined size, rather than the browser deciding how big my elements should be. If apply `width:100%` on `.control-group`, this happens:

[image: Extra space I can't get rid of]

The orange is a background colour applied to the table cell `control-group-item`. The issue seems to be with the 'submit' input: the submit stays the size it should be but browsers universally add extra space next to it within the table cell. So if I apply `width:100%` to each `.control-group-input`, I get this:

[image]

Which is OK, but stretches the ‘submit’ button. I can live with that, but is there any way to get it like the second image (but without the random space) using my current approach, or should I sack that off & try something different?

---

**Edit** I do not know the sizes of the inputs in advance: I can't set a width on them, which effectively rules out most inline block/float methods. I ideally need IE 8/9 support, which is why display:table was tried.

---

**Edit 2**: here are versions on Codepen: http://codepen.io/DanielCouper/pen/knDmC
After rewriting the code there, I realise my question is: how is the width of the table cells being calculated? It's specifically the cell with the submit button that has the extra space. The extra space seems random.

Comment: Could you show a live example here : http://jsfiddle.net/ Because it's hard to say what's wrong only with pictures

Comment: Did you try inline-block and percentage width's ?

Comment: Try to do it in fiddle and if problem still occurs we can edit it.

Comment: Can't do it in JSfiddle due to something being wrong with work network; can do it in Codepen, hence the link to the pen above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working version in codepen: http://codepen.io/mkleene/pen/ldqDH

The summary is that you need to remove the `width: 100%` on the submit button and then give the second table cell element `width: 100%`. You also need to make the textbox take up its entire parent with a `100%` width.

You also need to make sure that the `table` element is using an `auto` table layout.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you very much, that's working exactly as I needed. Ugh, I have been staring at form element markup and styling for far too long :(

Comment: Added classes to abstract it out, and it took a bit of fiddling to ensure I could use it for a variety of different possibilities, but all seems to be good. accepted

Answer (score 0):

nm, spoke too soon. Thought I had solved it, hadn't, was getting effects from some other CSS.